# How to add a variable name to a sensor data coming from remote XBee in python?

Tags: python, xbee

I am sending Temperature, Humidity and Light sensor data from a remote XBee module to a local one. The remote XBee is connected to a sensor board with STM32 microcontroller and two sensors, the data from the sensors is sent to a microconterller then to XBee in order to transfer it wirelessly to another XBee. I don't have any problem with the microcontroller part. but when I get the data from the remote XBee I want to display it in python. I am getting the correct data but I need to add variable names to my sensor data. for instance the first sensor data is the temperature data which comes as an integer and what I need is to see the temperature sensor values as; Temp = xx(integer values).
Here is the python code I used.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
from xbee import ZigBee

serial_port = serial.Serial('COM22', 9600)

zb = ZigBee(serial_port)

while True:
    try:
        print('Data Received from Xbee')
        data = zb.wait_read_frame() #Get data for later use

        #print data # for debugging only
        print data['rf_data']

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

serial_port.close()
```

and this is my python sensor data output

```
   Data Received from Xbee
23
32
103

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. Do all data come from the same serial port? How do you know which sensor is the source?

Comment: yes, all the data comes from the same serial port. I arranged it like that when I was writing the microcontroller codes, The first one is the temperature, the second is the humidity and the last one is the light sensor.

Comment: *"my python sensor data output"*: So, your frame data are separated with `\n`?

Comment: yes! the data coming from the remote XBee is separated with \n

Comment: Doesn't temp, hum, light = zb.wait_read_frame().split['\n'] work then?

Answer (score 0):

`print 'Temp = {}'.format(data['rf_data'])`

where `data['rf_data']` is your temperature data

`{}` will be replaced but what values you have in the format method in order

So if you have print `{} and {}'.format(1,2)` you will print `1 and 2`

Comment: The sensor values format order is like this; the first data which is 23 is the temp data, the second one which is 32 is the humidity data and the last one is the light sensor data. I need  to assign the first one as temp = 23, hum = 32, light = 103

Comment: So `zb.wait_read_frame()` will return all this 3 values? If yes, then you can unpack them like this: `temp, hum, light =  zb.wait_read_frame()` or `temp, hum, light =  zb.wait_read_frame()['rf_data']` if your method is a dictionary amd the key rf_data contains your data

Comment: Yeah, I tried to unpack them before but it didn't work!

Comment: Can you provide what `zb.wait_read_frame()` actually returns?

Comment: 23
32
103,    it returns these values, which also can change according to the room temperature.

Comment: Can you try like this `temp, hum, light = list(zb.wait_read_frame())` ? If the result is a string, you should split it like this before unpack `zb.wait_read_frame().split(' ')`